# Django Custom Commands don't work in Eclipse

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

I recently made some changes to my development environment and came across a problem. I have a  Django project in eclipse (using Pydev through the Aptana plugin), and I haven't been able to use any of my custom django commands.

If I try to run a custom command, I get the following output:

```
Unknown command: 'resetdb'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

...But if I run the command from the command line, it works.

I've tried debugging, to see why the custom command doesn't run, and it looks like django can't find `<project_name>.management`, but I'm not sure why this previously worked.

Any ideas as to why I can't get custom commands working?

In case it's a problem with any of the software (and not my project), I have the following setup:

- Eclipse Galileo (3.5.2)
- Django 1.3
- Aptana Studio 3.0.6
- Python 2.6
- Ubuntu 10.10

**EDIT:**

Project structure is as follows:

- Project/

  - src/

    - Main/

      - management/

        - commands/

          - custom_command.py
      - manage.py
      - settings.py

Installed Apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'Main', # Enables us to use custom commands
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    #... plus apps for the project
)
```

Comment: I took a look for me and it works properly without any problems -- have you added your project to the INSTALLED_APPS? It might be nice providing an overview of your structure (manage.py, app, settings) as it may be some organization issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your custom commands from Eclipse, make sure the correct settings.py file is being used to start the environment.  If Eclipse is somehow invoking the command with a default settings.py that doesn't have your apps listed, this is the effect you would see.

Comment: Hmmm... took a look at the settings file that is loaded. Definitely looks like the right `settings.py` file

Comment: just to double check... try dropping into the manage.py shell from Eclipse and then do "import settings", followed by "settings.INSTALLED_APPS."  Do you see your apps listed?

Comment: Yes, my apps are listed when I do that from Eclipse. When I debug, it's as though django doesn't detect my app as a Python module.